# General result of the following integral

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Let $I = \int\limits_0^\infty dx x^{2n} e^{-\alpha x^2}$
I tried it as follows:

with the substitution $y = x^2 \implies \frac{dy}{dx} = 2x \implies dx = \frac{dy}{2x}$ the integral transforms into $\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{dy}{2x} y^n e^{-\alpha y}$ with $y = x^2 \implies x = \pm \sqrt{y} $ we get: $\frac{1}{2} \int\limits_0^\infty dy$ $ y^{n \pm \frac{1}{2}} e^{-\alpha y} $ now if I integrate by parts I get:

$I = \frac{1}{2}[- \frac{1}{\alpha} e^{-\alpha y} y^{n \pm \frac{1}{2}}]_0^\infty + \frac{1}{2}  \int\limits_0^\infty -\frac{1}{\alpha} e^{-\alpha y} y^{n-\frac{3}{2}}(n \pm \frac{1}{2})$ where the term on the left is zero. On the right side the exponent of the $y$  could also be $y^{n-\frac{1}{2}}$ in case we chose the plus.

I would just go on partially integrating to get the solution in the end but I'm not really sure I did everything correct so far. Why is there an ambiguity with the $\pm$? How do I get rid of it? Did I do everything correct so far?

Cheers !

Comment: Compare your substitution integral with  $\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty t^{z-1} e^{-t}\,{\rm d}t$.  Also, you might be better off using $x^2 = y/\alpha$ making $x^{2n} = (y/\alpha)^n$.

Comment: Ignore the second sentence -- that doesn't make much difference.  However, I believe you can just use $x = +\sqrt{y}$, since you are only integrating over $x \ge 0$.  You _are_ in gamma-function territory.

Comment: Aah nice catch on the $x \geq 0$, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $I(a) = \displaystyle \int_0^{\infty} e^{-ax^2} dx$. We know that
$$I(a) = \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{a}}$$
Now note that
$$\dfrac{d^n I(a)}{da^n} = (-1)^n\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n} e^{-ax^2} dx$$
Hence, we have
$$\int_0^{\infty} x^{2n} e^{-ax^2} dx = (-1)^n \dfrac{d^n}{da^n} \left( \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2 \sqrt{a}}\right) = (-1)^n \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}2\left(-\dfrac12 \right)\left(-\dfrac32 \right) \cdots \left(-\dfrac{2n-1}2 \right)a^{-n-1/2}$$
which simplifies to
$$\color{red}{\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{2n} n!}\dfrac1{a^{n+1/2}}}$$

Comment: Thanks!  I was checking to see if I was using the gamma function correctly:  this is also written as $\frac{1}{2 \alpha^{n + 1/2}} \cdot \Gamma(n + \frac{1}{2})$ .

Comment: @RecklessReckoner Yes. Both are the same.

Comment: I was working from the direction of direct comparison of factors in the integrand in $\Gamma(z)$, so I was pleased that I got a result that agreed with yours.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try denoting the integral as $I_n$, then work out some recursion formula involving the $I_n$'s?

Answer (score 0):

One way of solving it is by setting $\alpha x^2 =z$ and getting the Gamma function after some substitiution and algebra
$$
I = \frac{1}{\alpha^{n-\frac{1}{2}}} \int _{0}^{\infty} z^{n +\frac{1}{2}}e^{-z}dz
$$
here $x = \sqrt{\frac{z}{\alpha}}$ because you only need the positive value of $x$, as defined by the integral's boundaries.

Comment: Since $dx = \frac{dz}{2\sqrt{\alpha z}}$, shouldn't that be $\frac{1}{2 \alpha^{n+1/2}} \int_0^{\infty} z^{n-\frac{1}{2}} e^{-z} dz$ ?